# How do I write a function which takes a generic enum and prints it if it contains a String?

Tags: generics, enums, rust

I have a generic enum:

```
enum Holder<T> {
    None,
    One(T),
    Two(T, T),
}
```

and I have placed two strings in it:

```
let two_strings = Holder::Two(String::from("abc"), String::from("abc"));
```

I want to write a function which takes the enum, checks if it is of type `String` and prints it:

```
fn print_name_from_enum<T>(hold: T) {
    match hold {
        Holder::Two(a, b) => println!("Your Name is {} {}", a, b),
    }
}
```

The compiler complains because I do not specify the type of `holder`:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         Holder::Two(a, b) => println!("Your Name is {} {}", a, b),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found enum `Holder`
   |
   = note: expected type `T`
              found type `Holder<_>`
```

but if I give the type:

```
match hold {
    Holder<String>::Two(a, b) => {
        println!("Your Name is {} {}", a, b)
    }
}
```

the compiler complains as well:

```
error: expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|`, found `<`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:15
   |
10 |         Holder<String>::Two(a, b) => {
   |               ^ expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|` here
```

How do I solve this issue? What am I doing wrong here?

**Solution**

Thanks to @mcarton I found the mistake. The way it should be is

```
fn print_name_from_enum<T: ToString>(hold: Holder<T>) {
    match hold {
        Holder::Two(a, b) => {
            println!("Your Name is {first} {second}", first = a.to_string(), 
                                                        second = b.to_string())
        }
        _ => {
            println!("ooPPs.")
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add the enum type as an argument, and for T it has to be add that its function to_string() is implemented.

Comment: `fn print_name_from_enum<T>(hold: T)`, this does not say `print_name_from_enum` takes a parameter of type `Holder`, but rather any type with no constraint at all. Did you mean `print_name_from_enum<T>(hold: Holder<T>)`?

Comment: _"a function which takes the enum, checks if it is of string type and prints it"_ — This isn't possible. For the function to take the enum, it must be known at compile-time what the parameter `T` is. So a function can't really "test" that - if it needs it to be a string then it will either compile or won't compile.

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=53996aa7d42c97f6289e06935239b41f&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).